# Принцип работы авторизации по смс, NODE JS?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

сделал простую авторизацию и регистрацию на MERN ( Node JS + React).
Сейчас появилось идея сделать простую регистрацию авторизацию лишь по средствам sms( информацию о себе, е-майл пользователи смогут добавить в личном кабинете) .

Идея такога, сделать регистрацию лишь с одним полем по SMS

Пользователь вводит свой телефон, и на backend генерируется код из 6 цифр, который по средстам api смс сервиса отправляется на номер. В браузере же ( на стороне фронта) появляется форма с вводом этих 6 символов и чтением, так же браузер ожидает что для этой сессии, будет введен код. Для безопасности думаю его стоит прогнать через bcrypt, и когда пользователь вводит код, то через bcrypt.compare провреить действителен ли код.
Единственный вопрос, по поводу сессии. Не могу понять как сделать что бы проверка была именно внутри одной сессии, а не другой. Или может моя логика вовсе не верна и стоит сделать авторизацию по другому?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Когда сгенерировали код для смс, запишите куда то (в базу, в файл) соответствие код и некий id пользователя. Этот же id уйдет в форму, которую Вы отправите пользователю. Когда пользователь введет код с смс, то на сервер Вам придет пара смс код-id пользователя. И теперь проверить их не составит труда.

Также хорошо рядышком в базе запомнить и время генерации кода и для место для количества попыток.

Да, этот id пользователя может быть id сессии. Но все зависит от того, какие библиотеки-фреймворки Вы используете.

Нужно ли что то шифровать через bcrypt? вряд ли. Если все проверки будут на сервере, то обычного https хватит с головой (Вы же не собирались смс код и в браузер отправлять??)